# Can an app be build to send notification to non-app user

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to create an app that can send notification to the user who does not have the same app installed on his device.

I have come acrossed 'Push Notification' service via GCM and FCM but it requires the app being installed on both the devices to communicate or send notification.
(P.S- No suggestion for web application to user mobile service)

Comment: No.. there should obviously be a receiver on the receiving device

Answer (score 0):

You can use other means of communication like SMS or email.

Answer (score 0):

No. Notifications even though coming from Android Google servers are part of the app environment. So you cannot send an app notification to non app users. If that was the case imagine getting app notifications from Amazon and whatnot.
But you can use some other means like mail, sending links of your app via mail/sending invites via mail or SMS.